# APK apresenta falhas continuamente

Tags: java, android, apk

A minha a APK abre corretamente quando o código é este:

```
 package com.example.wheresmybusdriver;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Localizacao extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_localizacao);
    }

    public void sairLogin(View view){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Porém quando eu adiciono ao código:

```
TextView statusLocation = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textStatus);

    public void informeStatusSim(View view) {
        statusLocation.setText("Sua localização esta sendo transmitida!");
    }

    public void informeStatusNao(View view) {
        statusLocation.setText("Sua localização não esta sendo transmitida!");
    }
```

Ficando assim o resultado:

```
package com.example.wheresmybusdriver;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Localizacao extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_localizacao);
    }

    public void sairLogin(View view){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    TextView statusLocation = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textStatus);

    public void informeStatusSim(View view) {
        statusLocation.setText("Sua localização esta sendo transmitida!");
    }

    public void informeStatusNao(View view) {
        statusLocation.setText("Sua localização não esta sendo transmitida!");
    }
}
```

O apk não abre e aparece a mensagem ("apk" apresenta falhas continuamente). 
Acho estranho que quando eu entro no meu apk, eu vou para a página inicial dele, sendo assim, funciona corretamente, mas quando eu clico no botão para entrar na Activity com o código acima, ele para de funcionar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você está procurando por um elemento do layout fora de qualquer método da sua activity `Localizacao`, fazendo com que o código seja executado **antes** de você definir o layout com `setContent`:

```java
TextView statusLocation = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textStatus);
```

Para resolver, você deve fazer a declaração dessa variável fora (como um campo da sua classe) e a atribuição de valor no `onCreate`, por exemplo.

```java
public class Localizacao extends AppCompatActivity {
    TextView statusLocation;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_localizacao);

        // Uma vez que você já indicou qual é o layout com "setContent", você pode procurar
        // pelo elemento "textStatus"
        statusLocation = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textStatus);
    }

    //...
}
```

---

A propósito, `"apk" apresenta falhas continuamente` não é a sua mensagem de erro. Para encontrar a mensagem de erro veja o Logcat do Android Studio. Uma vez que você esteja lendo a mensagem de erro correta, ficará mais claro o que você deve procurar entender para corrigir o problema.

`"apk" apresenta falhas continuamente` é uma mensagem que aparece no Android quando o usuário abre um aplicativo que **quebra** (*crash*) continuamente. Se você abrir qualquer aplicativo que ocorra esse problema, essa mensagem aparecerá, não precisa ser um aplicativo seu ou um aplicativo em desenvolvimento.

Comment: Fiz isso e agora funcionou, obrigado.